# Rails LinkedIn API gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

I am using the Rails LinkedIn API gem. https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/issues/141

I am trying to search linked in users by first and last name and so far I've come up with this:

```
@profiles = linkedin_client.search(:first_name => fname, :last_name => lname, :sort => "connections", :fields => %w(id first-name last-name headline industry location api-standard-profile-request picture_url public_profile_url summary));
```

One question I have is, will ":first_name" work as the parameter "first-name"? What I mean is will the underscore be a good substitute for the dash "-"?

I'm hoping these results would be organized by connection, as I've tried to do above with `:sort => "connections"`

The problem is that it will not return any results, even when I know the user's name exists. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :first_name only as the parameter.

first-name will not work !

Comment: i also found in some cases that just using a string will work like "first-name"